# Draw rectangles over bitmapimage in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I'm trying to figure out the best way to draw rectangles over a Image in wpf. When the user clicks somewhere in a thumbnail Image the region the user clicks should be marked with a semi-transparent rectangle. This is easy. I just add a rectangle with some opacity on a canvas that is placed over the BitmapImage. The problem is when the user clicks the same region multiple times, then a new rectangle will be added over the previous rectangle and because of the semi-transparency the combined rectangles will the be darker. Please look at the image:

[image]

So, my question is: How should I draw the rectangles to prevent this behavior? Not matter how many times the user clicks a region or overlapped region the area will always have the same semi-transparent color.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want a new rectangle to make the previous one dissapear or prevent darkening when combining multiple rectangles.

**If You want to show only a single Rectangle**

Instead of creating a new `Rectangle` each time, use only a single `Rectangle` element (it can be even defined when the form starts) and hide it. Then, when the user clicks on the thumbnail just show this `Rectangle` and set the its position and size appropriately.

**If You want to combine multiple Rectangles without darkening effect**

One possible way to control how overlapping rectangles' colors blend is to use `Path` and add `RectangleGeometry` objects to a `GeometryGroup` with `FillRule="NonZero"` set. Take a look at this article for more information: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/05/combining-paths-in-xaml-for-silverlight.html.